# Code Emit and Expressions

Tags: c#, lambda

I am using Code Emit for dynamic code generation.
I would like to set a field using an external factory method.
Here is my (reduced) code:

Defines:

```
    Func<object> fact = () => new B();
    var mi = fact.GetMethodInfo();
    var t = typeof(B);
```

Emit code:

```
    ILGenerator ilg;
    var tb = _mb.DefineType("myProxy", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class, typeof(object));
    var fieldBuilder = tb.DefineField("proxy", t, FieldAttributes.Private);
    var ctorBuilder = tb.DefineConstructor(...);

    ilg = ctorBuilder.GetILGenerator();

    ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(object).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
    ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, mi);
    ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, t);
    ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);
    ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Create an instace:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(tb.CreateType());
```

**TargetInvocationException** is thrown

> {"Method not found: \"?\"."}

Here is what I am looking forward to generate:

```
public class A
{
    private B _proxy;
    public A(Func<object> factory)
    {
        _proxy = (B)factory();
    }
}
```

**BUT** the factory Method is fixed and not provided as parameter...

```
public class A
{
    private B _proxy;
    public A()
    {
        _proxy = (B) //[GENERATE ME] () => new B();
    }
}
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you compile the expression?

Comment: Just edited the questsion, it's different now :)

Comment: Well you creating an object of type object and you are calling a method with created object as a parameter, but your function declaration does not accept any parameter (mi). If you can post what exactly you want to do, someone can suggest correct code. What exactly you want to emit?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Create an object and then set a field?

Comment: Create an object using a Factory Method. The Method is defined outside the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to invoke delegate via "Invoke" method but you need to give factory delegate to your proxy. You can add a parameter to your proxy constructor.

```
public class B
{
}

static internal class Metadata<T> //Avoid lock & string metadata description
{
    static public readonly Type Type = typeof(T);

    static public FieldInfo Field<X>(Expression<Func<T, X>> expression)
    {
        return (expression.Body as MemberExpression).Member as FieldInfo;
    }

    static public PropertyInfo Property<X>(Expression<Func<T, X>> expression)
    {
        return (expression.Body as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo;
    }

    static public MethodInfo Method(Expression<Action<T>> expression)
    {
        return (expression.Body as MethodCallExpression).Method;
    }

    static public MethodInfo Method<X>(Expression<Func<T, X>> expression)
    {
        return (expression.Body as MethodCallExpression).Method;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var _Factory = new Func<object>(() => new B());

        TypeBuilder _TypeBuilder = null;// = ...;
        var _Parameters = new Type[] { Metadata<Func<object>>.Type };
        var _Constructor = _TypeBuilder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.HasThis, _Parameters);
        var _Body = _Constructor.GetILGenerator();
        //...
        _Body.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        _Body.Emit(OpCodes.Call, Metadata<Func<object>>.Method(_Func => _Func.Invoke()));
        //...

        var _Type = _TypeBuilder.CreateType();
        var _Parameter = Expression.Parameter(Metadata<Func<object>>.Type);
        var _New = Expression.Lambda<Func<Func<object>, object>>(Expression.New(_Type.GetConstructor(_Parameters), _Parameter), _Parameter).Compile();

        var _Instance = _New(_Factory);
    }
}
```

Comment: Another alternative is to work with Expression<Func<object>> instead of Func<object> and emit in static method of you factory using Expression.Lambda.CompileToMethod() and call your static method.